# Limit of $\frac{x\sin(\pi\|x\|)}{\|x\|}$ as x approaches 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have read the following statement. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x \text{sin}(\pi\|x\|)}{\|x\|}=0$$

I have to admit that I haven't worked with limits for a while, which is why I can't formally prove this (although I suspect the proof might be very elementary). The intuition is quite clear and I am only looking for a way to formally prove the equality above, so if anyone knows how to prove the statement formally, I would be very grateful. I know that

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

if this is needed. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How's this limit $0$? as the limit is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)}{||x||}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)\cdot\pi}{\pi||x||}=\pi$

Comment: @PNDas I am sorry, I forgot an $x$ in the equation. I edited the question.

Comment: Now you have edited it $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin(\pi||x||)}{||x||}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)\cdot x\pi}{\pi||x||}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)}{\pi||x||}\lim_{x\to0}x\pi=\pi\cdot0=0$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$.

As $\pi ||x|| \underset{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$ and $\frac{\sin(s)}{s} \underset{s \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 1$, one has by composition of limits:

$$
\frac{\sin(\pi ||x||)}{||x||} x =\pi \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi ||x||)}{\pi ||x||} x \underset{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} \pi \cdot 1 \cdot 0_{\mathbb{R}^n} = 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, why is $\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)}{\pi||x||} \to 1$ formally? It would make sense intuitively.

Comment: Simply because $\pi || x || \underset{x \to 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}}{\longrightarrow} 0_{\mathbb{R}}$. It is very formal in fact (look at some general theorem on limits composition). $x \to 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ **means** $|| x || \longrightarrow 0_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, I think one has to look at the continuation of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ in $0$, though, before using such a theorem. I was simply forgetting about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now you have edited it $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin(\pi||x||)}{||x||}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)\cdot x\pi}{\pi||x||}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi||x||)}{\pi||x||}\lim_{x\to0}x\pi=\pi\cdot0=0$$